# How to test broadcast receiver is executed in unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I need to invoke a method on main thread, for that purpose i am using @UiThreadTest and calling the method inside my test.
That method is responsible to send broadcast receiver. 
So i am registering the receiver and setting a boolean value to test if broadcast has been sent or not.
In logs i am able to see the broadcast is executed. 
But getting assertion failure error inside test.
Is this some threading issue?

//broadcase receiver

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
       if (mUiUpdateReceiver != null && intent.getAction().equals(MessageCenter.INTENT_UI_REFRESH)) {
           mbroadcastFlag = true;
       }
    }
}
```

//test

```
@UiThreadTest
    public void test_broadcast () throws Exception{
        mUiUpdateReceiver = new Receiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(SampleClass.INTENT_REFRESH);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mAppContext).registerReceiver(mUiUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);

        mbroadcastFlag = false;
        sampleClass.method();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        assertTrue(mbroadcastFlag);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mAppContext).unregisterReceiver(mUiUpdateReceiver);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Konstantin Loginov's answear is ok, but it uses JUnit3 (because he extends ApplicationTestCase; if you extend any TestCase class Android framework will run your tests with JUnit3 runner by default).

If you want to use newer JUnit 4 You can use something like this:

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 boolean flag;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri packageName = intent.getData();
        if(packageName.toString().equals("package:" + context.getPackageName())){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Test itself:

```
public class MyReceiverTest {

    Context context;


    @Before
    public void init() {
        context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), "test_");
    }

    @Test
    public void myReceiverTest() throws InterruptedException {

        MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();

    //remeber to change Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED 
//with your action name from your mainfest file
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED));
        String pn = context.getPackageName();



        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        boolean b = receiver.flag;
        assertTrue(b);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        assertTrue(true);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you a small hello-world with broadcast receiver and unit test for it.

Here's my broadcast receiver:

```
public class UiRefreshReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    boolean broadcastFlag;

    public UiRefreshReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        broadcastFlag = true;
    }
}
```

And test class for it:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void test_broadcast () throws Exception{
        UiRefreshReceiver mUiUpdateReceiver = new UiRefreshReceiver();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mUiUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter("my-event"));

        assertFalse(mUiUpdateReceiver.broadcastFlag);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent("my-event"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        assertTrue(mUiUpdateReceiver.broadcastFlag);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mUiUpdateReceiver);

    }
}
```

I hope, it'd help.

Though, in my humble opinion - it's enough to simply unit-test onReceive() code.